# Sandbox restricting freopen Mac OS X

Tags: macos, redirect, operating-system, sandbox

So I've got an app that was working nicely but when the sandbox was announced I figured I might as well as start complying.  In my app the user can call python and what I had been doing was a simple redirect of stdout and stderr

```
freopen("error.log","w",stderr);
```

and then call Python via a

```
status = PyRun_SimpleString(utfString);
```

From there I can simple readback results/errors and go on with life.  However with the sandbox this is not permitted as /dev/stdout and /dev/stderr are outside of my app.  I tried putting in temporary file exceptions in the entitlements:

```
com.apple.security.temporary-exception.files.absolute-path.read-write => Array
{
    Item 0 => /dev/stdout
    Item 1 => /dev/stderr
}
```

But that didn't help either...

Does anyone know how to work around this?  This code was working fine and I understand the sandboxing but I'd like to keep the python interface simple and a quick redirect seems acceptable to me; after all, Everyone can write and read to stdout/stderr....

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The answer was the path was incorrect, with the sandbox, the redirect was fine but you need to do it to a file within the NSDocumentsDirectory...  So, if you start thinking iOS-like you're good, no magic, just recall writing needs to be done in your app's documents directory and redirects for stdout/stderr are writes...